# How to run python scripts in Synapse in production environments

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

How can we run python scripts in Synapse in production environments? I want to know the best practices.

Answer (score -1):

> You can use **custom activities** in an Azure Data Factory or **Azure Synapse Analytics pipeline** to run Python scripts.

For more details, refer to below links:

- [Use custom activities in an Azure Data Factory or Azure Synapse Analytics pipeline](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity)
- [Tutorial: Run Python scripts through Azure Data Factory using Azure Batch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/tutorial-run-python-batch-azure-data-factory)